# add event handler for leaving input box

Tags: c#, event-handling, telerik

I want to add some handling in server side after user input something in the inputbox. When the user leaves the input box. So the handling will be triggered in server side. Here is the code in 
InstantiateIn of Itemplate.

```
public class UsageColumnTemplate : ITemplate
{
    private RadNumericTextBox _inputBox;

    public UsageColumnTemplate(string cName, string controlIDNumber, string idValue, DataSet currencies)
    {
        _colname = cName;
        _controlIDNumber = controlIDNumber;
        _idValue = idValue;
    }
    public void InstantiateIn(System.Web.UI.Control container)
    {
        _inputBox = new RadNumericTextBox();
        _inputBox.ID = "uiInputBox_" + _controlIDNumber;
        _inputBox.Width = Unit.Pixel(100);
        _inputBox.IncrementSettings.InterceptMouseWheel = false;
        _inputBox.ClientEvents.OnKeyPress = "keyPressInGrid";
        _inputBox.Attributes.Add("onkeydown", "keyPressInGrid2(this, event)"); 
    }
}
```

How can I add an function to handle the input where user leave the focus of input box?

Comment: The server side doesn't know what the client is doing until the browser communicates back to the server. You need something on the client side to transmit to the server when the client side event occurs.